# Why are my CSS variables not recognized in Django?

Tags: css, django, variables

I'm writing some CSS for a Django project and ran into an issue with CSS variables. I've used them in plenty of other sites but this is my first try in Django. I tested that the CSS is working by manipulating the font size so I know my static files are serving correctly. However, it seems that the CSS variable syntax does not work in Django. Is this correct? I can't seem to find any info on this when searching.

EDIT

Here's some more info:
my settings.py file - this did work as I was able to apply other styles to elements.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)
```

and my css code

```
/* ----- Variables ----- */
:root {
    --blue-primary: rgb(56, 117, 181)
    --grey-primary: rgb(242, 242, 242)
    --blue-secondary: rgb(41, 171, 226)
    --dark-grey: rgb(153, 153, 153)
}

/* ----- Color ----- */
h1 {
    color: var(--blue-primary);
    font-size: 130px;
}
```

and then my link in the html document:

```
<link
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
            href="{% static 'server/css/base.css' %}"
        />
```

The only thing not working is the variables. When I changed the h1 color to use the rgb code that I had put in the variable the site properly updated.

Comment: Can you give details about what you did? Can you show (relevant parts) of the template, and what you did to let Django serve static files?

Comment: did you add the static views to the `urls.py`?

Comment: I did not add anything to the urls.py but don't see why that would not allow me to use variables when all other aspects of the css file are working fine without being included in the urls.py.

Comment: because Django needs to add the views that serve the static files to the urls. Otherwise there is no path to download the images. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'm struggling to comprehend why I would need to do this. I'm not serving any images when trying to load CSS variables, the same RGB code works when input directly rather than using the CSS variable, and I set up all other aspects of the project following the Django docs.